# Javascript event for new button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that contains a list of `jobs`. Depending on the state of a `job`, there will be certain buttons for that job. In order to make my app feel more like a native app, when the state of one of those jobs changes, I use javascript to add a new html button without refreshing the page. That newly added html button has a class with a javascript event tied to it. But whenever I click that button the event that should be triggered never goes off. Here is some examples:

**Properly working button that is created when the page is refreshed**

```
<div id="user_completed<%= i %>">
          <% if !is_runner?(@user) && job.status == 'assigned' %>
            <div class="row job-buttons" id="user_completed_button_row<%= i %>">
              <div class="small-6 columns">
                <div class="button small success radius user_completed_button" data-job-id="<%= i %>">job completed</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

**Button that is added with javascript**

```
        var user_completed = '<div class="row job-buttons" id="user_completed_button_row' + id + '">' +
                                '<div class="small-6 columns">' +
                                    '<div class="button small success radius user_completed_button" data-job-id="' + id + '">job completed</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                              '</div>';
        var user_completed_div = "#user_completed" + id;
        $(user_completed_div).html(user_completed);
```

These are the two buttons that are supposed to be equivalent. The first button is created when a job is in the "completed" state upon refreshing the page, and the second button is created when the job is in the "completed" state and the page is not refreshed. These two buttons should have the exact same HTML.

Now when the first button is clicked, the javascript event goes off without a hitch, but when the second button is clicked, the javascript event will not fire at all. I keep checking the chrome developer tool and they seem to have exactly the same HTML.

Here is the event I am trying to trigger.

```
  $('.user_completed_button').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('job-id');
    var url = "/jobs/" + id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: url,
      data: {job: {status: "completed"}},
      async: false, 
    });
  });
```

Side note: I am using the javascript plugin pusher as well as turbolinks. I have no idea if this makes a difference or not, just thought id mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though maybe you are binding the click handler before the element is on the page, and jQuery will only bind to the elements in the list at the time the binding happens.

To make sure you can get dynamically created elements, add the listener to a parent object and use `on` as suggested (or `delegate` if you have an older jQuery)

```
$('#user_completed_holder_or_whatnot').on('click', '.user_completed_button', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('job-id');
    var url = "/jobs/" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: url,
        data: {job: {status: "completed"}},
        async: false, 
    });
});
```

This says that for any click on the holder ('#user_completed_holder_or_whatnot') if the target of the click matches the selector passed for the second argument ('.user_completed_button') then run the handle method.

Edit: You can also re-bind after dynamically creating the element, but that adds potential performance overhead or can make your code messy.

Answer (score 1):

To handle events for dynamically created DOM objects your should use jQuery `on` method. Something like this

```
 $('.user_completed_button').on('click', function(event) { ... })
```

More docs here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: But the code you've shown does exactly the same thing as the OP's `$('.user_completed_button').click(function(e) {...})`. Yes, `.on()` _can_ handle dynamically created elements, but that doesn't mean it will unless you actually tell it to...

Comment: You're wrong. OP's code bind click handler to DOM element only once - when called. And it bind to elements that exist in DOM at this moment.

My code dynamically binds listener to any element in DOM no matter when it was created.

Comment: No _you_ are wrong. Please actually read the documentation you linked to, especially all of the "Direct and delegated events" section. As I said before, `.on()` can work for dynamically created elements, but for it to do so you have to supply slightly different parameters, and you have to call it on a parent/ancestor element that actually exists at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the listener to the `document` so the button can be added later:

```
$(document).on('click', '.user_completed_button', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data('job-id');
  var url = "/jobs/" + id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: url,
    data: {job: {status: "completed"}},
    async: false, 
  });
});
```

This is equivalent to jQuery's deprecated/removed [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.